# Will the second beam have higher or lower stiffness in X direction than the first beam?

Tags: finite-element-method, stiffness

Attached is a picture of two beams. The second beam has exactly the same properties and dimensions as the first one, but is rotated, say, by 45 degrees. I want to know if the second beam will have higher or lower stiffness in the X direction than the first beam. And an exlpanation for the answer will be appreciated.
[image]

The reason for asking this question is that when I was going over the Geometric Non-linearity effect inside a FEA software (like ANSYS), I read that if Large-Rotations are expected inside the model during solution, then Geometric Non-linearity should be turned ON. When I further researched that why does Large-Rotation need to have Geometric Non-linearity turned ON, it was discovered that the stiffness matrix changes  because "*If an element's oreintation changes (rotation), then the transformation of its local stiffness into global components will change*", [as cited in Practical Finite Element Analysis, 1st Edition, Nitin].

[image]

I just want to understand the reason that why would changing the orientation (by rotating the beam) will change the local stiffness in a specific direction or axis, like X axis.

Comment: The answer depends on the material properties., the end constraints, and probably other things as well.  (For example if the beam buckles, do you consider that as "stiffness?") I would guess your question is making some unstated assumptions, possibly based on a "strength of materials" notion of what a "beam" is.

Comment: I would add loading also as a prominent factor that affects "stiffness"

Comment: B is shorter in the X axis than A.

Comment: Maybe I didn't clarify my question clearly. If you think in terms of stiffness matrix only (in FEA), then it is only dependent upon the material properties and dimensions. Thats why I wrote that these properties are the same. What kind of constraints, loads, etc generally don't control the stiffness matrix. So apparently, I was thinking that the stiffness should also be the same for both of these beams. However, I discovered later that the stiffness of these two beams is not the same in X direction. I couldn't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: @SolarMike, so it means that the Body B is more stiff than A in X axis? Moreover, the cross sectional area of Body B is also going to be higher than A if a perpendicular cut to X axis is taken. These things are overall making me believe that Body B is more stiff than A along X axis.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq so you have not read, or perhaps understood, the answer given?

Comment: @SolarMike, answer by you or someone else? Because you just mentioned a fact.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq you should check out what are comments on here and what are answers.

Comment: @SolarMike, people sometimes try to answer the question under comment section so it becomes confusing. So I didn't know were you answering or just making a comment. Anyways, I added a comment to the 'Answer' provided as well. Regarding the comment I made here, (about the length and cross sec area about X axis), do you agree that the Body B is more stiff than A?

Comment: To clarify: do you want an explanation why the second beam will not widthstand as great a force exerted on it in (positive?) x direction as the first beam will?

Comment: @Jpe61, no. We know that Body B will not withstand a greater force in X axis than Body A because of the additional moment that has to be generated because of the distance between the supports (Now I am assuming that the left end of the beams are fixed since you brought this question up) and the force applied is now significant. My question is only to understand that does the beam orientation play a role in changing the stiffness of it along a specific direction or not?

Comment: I'm nitpicking here, but the material properties do not change when the orientation of an object changes. For a non-symmetric object the properties of an object *along different axis* are of course different. And whether the beams are fixed or hinged in their ends plays no role here. Beam B wil give first.

Comment: @alephzero, I have edited my question. Maybe it can be more clear enough for the readers to understand. Please go through it.

Answer (score 2):

The stiffness is the same for both, as the properties of each are identical along its longitudinal (x) axis, and $(\dfrac{EI}{L})_A = (\dfrac{EI}{L})_B$.

However, for the physical length is the same, given the same loading, beam A will experience a higher moment and deflect more, as its vertical projected length (the loading span) is longer ($L_B = L_A cos\theta$).

**ADD:** The sketch below reflects the point I was making in response to your latest comment/question. The beams are assumed to have the same span length (horizontal dimension in the global "X" axis.

Note that for the case of the inclined beam, the force component normal to the beam axis "*x*" is ignored, since it has no significance in comparing the rigidity of the beams, but represents a stability concern.

[image]

**Final Note:** My last piece for you to think about is whether your question on the relative rigidity of a horizontal beam and an inclined beam based on the global X-axis (horizontal) has a legit theoretical base that merits extensive discussion.

[image]

Comment: I know the properties are the same along its longitudinal axis. Therefore each of the beam's stiffness should be the same along its longitudinal axis. That is evident in the question. That is why I was asking about the stiffness along X axis only. Regarding your second para, yeah so it is understood that the stiffness of Body B is higher than that of A. But what you are talking about is subjective to loading condition. I was, in general, asking about the stiffness of the beam along X axis only.

Comment: For any beam, the reactions are assumed to act on the beam centerline using the Cartesian coordinate system, which ties the cross-sectional properties of the beam and forms the baseline for the development of beam equations and calculations of beam properties and reactions. Strictly to say, for an inclined beam, the calculations based on the global coordinate system violates all beam/mechanics theories, therefore they are meaningless. Once you've rotated everything on the global coordinate system (axes) to conform to the angle of inclination, then you will find the results are the same.

Comment: I have edited my original question in case if it was not clear enough. Please go through it again.

Comment: The short answer to your update is that the beam theory was developed for small deflection, for which linear elastic behavior is holding valid. As I have shown in the sketches when rotating an object to inclination, there is an eccentricity and additional component force that causing the object to rotate in space and result in large displacement that is beyond the scope of linear elastic behavior. If you feel this answer does not answer your question, I suggest opening a new post with the latest update to draw new responses.

Comment: I think this article should be on your "MUST READ" list. Pay attention to "geometric nonlinearity" https://www.mechead.com/what-is-linear-and-nonlinear-analysis/#:~:text=A%20nonlinear%20analysis%20is%20an%20analysis%20where%20a,deformations%29%2C%20material%20nonlinearity%E2%80%99s%20%28i.e.%20elasto-plastic%20material%29%2C%20and%20contact.

Comment: well the thing to know is that the large displacement and large rotation are two different things, basically. Large displacement changes the stiffness of the FEM elements and hence the stiffness matrix needs to be updated (so that the actual stiffness during solution can be tracked) which makes the force-displacement relation non-linear. However, large rotation can happen when the structure is not undergoing large displacement. Therefore, stiffness of the structure can still be considered as constant (because no large displacement exists) and force-displacement linear  relation should hold.

Comment: However, the stiffness matrix still needs to be updated in FEM when large rotation takes place. This will not render the force-displacement relation become non-linear in the local co-oridnate system of the body, however, the stiffness matrix should be updated with new values of the stiffness of the structure along the global co-ordinates / components. This is my main question. That why would a high rotation make the stiffness become different in global co-oridnates / components. I mean what is the science behind it.

Comment: and yes I have read the link to the document which you have added. The problem is that I can re-ask the question by opening a new one, but that is exactly going to be the same what I am asking here. And I don't understand why was the question closed. It was just a simple question which was better clarified with additional comments. This is a basic phenomenon which happens and I was asking if anybody knew the reason behind it. Apparently, only you answered and the question was closed. I can open a new one but I fear that is going to be closed as well.

Comment: You should have more straightforward with your real concern - properties that causing nonlinearity, but you have chosen to put a question that many people think is a trivial matter. I will stay away from your new post though.